# SFDX source:retrieve Custom Settings from Org?

Tags: salesforcedx, customsetting, vs-code

From within a vscode SFDX project, I'd like to retrieve and eventually manage / set custom settings from within my project.

Command that I'm using for this is a standard CLI call of `source:retrieve` - nothing fancy.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_retrieve

[image: Custom Settings]

Expected solution is something like:
`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomSettings`
(Obviously, this does not work)

Comment: Did you also specify a namespace prefix? Like tcsfl__AdminSettings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Settings are actually implemented as Custom Objects:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:AdminSetting__c
```

Make sure you use the API name, including `__c`.